# How do I add Git to MSBuild script?

Tags: git, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm trying to add Git check-in as part of my MSBuild script. I want to:

1. Commit the files with a message
2. Push the commit
3. Tag the build
4. Push the tag

The build script is in ./Build/ (where . is the solution folder).

I'm using:

```
<Target Name="Committed" DependsOnTargets="SignedInstaller">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(GitInstallationFolderPath)cmd\git.exe&quot; --git-dir=..\.git --work-tree=.. commit -m &quot;$(Changes)&quot;"/>
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(GitInstallationFolderPath)cmd\git.exe&quot; --git-dir=..\.git --work-tree=.. push"/>
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(GitInstallationFolderPath)cmd\git.exe&quot; --git-dir=..\.git --work-tree=.. tag -a v$(VersionNumber) -m &quot;$(Changes)&quot;"/>
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(GitInstallationFolderPath)cmd\git.exe&quot; --git-dir=..\.git --work-tree=.. push -- tags"/>
</Target>
```

The custom properties are all OK.

The first commit exits with 1 and breaks the build.

I'm not sure if I just need to tweak this, or if I'm going about it all wrong, so advice would be welcome. I need to do some to add any new files to Git too - just haven't got that far yet. I do want to stick with MSBuild, though as we have a lot of scripts now. I just want to remove my SVN targets and move to Git.

Comment: I believe you will need to start an instance of a bash terminal (mingw32, cygwin).  Then run your Git commands through that terminal.

Comment: https://github.com/WilbertOnGithub/MSBuildGitTasks There are already projects to integrate Git commands into MSBuild, so probably you don't need to call <Exec>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw this, but it looks like it only has one task - cloning - unless I'm misunderstanding the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the limited features of the GitTasks found in MSBuild Extensions, there seems to be more general purpose stuff in the [Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks).

```
GitBranch   A task to get the name of the branch or tag of git repository
GitClient   A task for Git commands.
GitCommits  A task for git to retrieve the number of commits on a revision.
GitDescribe     A task for git to get the most current tag, commit count since tag, and commit hash.
GitPendingChanges   A task for git to detect if there are pending changes
GitVersion  A task for git to get the current commit hash.
```